# Change layout when objects are not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have 4 objects on screen: (UIView or UIButton)

```
A B C D
```

In some cases I'll need to hide one or more of them that will result this:

```
A   C D
```

or this:

```
A     D
```

Is there a way in iOS 5 (**Can't use`AutoLayout`**) (beside using a lot of **ifs** and set the location programmatically) to trim the spaces and force the example above to look like this:

```
A C D
 A D
```

Comment: I guess there is no easy way. You need to write the code to change the frame or transform.

Comment: Luckily I only have 1-4 objects to show. What if I need to show and hide around 10 objects? That's a lot of ifs.

Comment: Use Key Value Observing(KVO). When a view is hidden you will get the message and accordingly you can shift your other views. You dont need many ifs in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I used KVO to achieve this.
**Step 1:** Register `ViewController` as observer for change of hidden property in all the views.

```
[_view1 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"hidden" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];
[_view2 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"hidden" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];
[_view3 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"hidden" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];
[_view4 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"hidden" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:NULL];
```

**Step 2:** Add method to respond to change notifications in `ViewController`

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
  if(![object isEqual:[viewArray lastObject]]){
    UIView *viewToHide = (UIView *)object;
    CGRect newFrame = viewToHide.frame;
    CGRect oldFrame;
    int indexOfObject = [viewArray indexOfObject:object];
    for(int i = indexOfObject + 1; i < viewArray.count; i++){
      UIView *viewToChange = [viewArray objectAtIndex:i];
      if(viewToChange.hidden){
        continue;
      }
      else{
      oldFrame = viewToChange.frame;
      viewToChange.frame = newFrame;
      [viewArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:viewToChange];
      newFrame = oldFrame;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Step 3:** I am hiding Views on tapping on them. You can of course achieve this whatever way you want.

```
- (IBAction)viewTapped :(UIGestureRecognizer *)recogniser{
  CGPoint touchPoint = [recogniser locationInView:self.view];
  UIView *touchView = [self.view hitTest:touchPoint withEvent:nil];
  if([touchView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]){
    touchView.hidden = YES;
  }
}
```